# initialize event in EKEventEditViewController

Tags: iphone

My code is following

```
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];


// set the addController's event store to the current event store.
addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;

// present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
[self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

addController.editViewDelegate = self;
[addController release];
```

It will appear new event ViewController. I want to initialize title and note in EKEventEditViewController.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a way.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.startDate = event_date;
event.endDate   = event_date;
event.notes=event_note;


EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];


// set the addController's event store to the current event store.
addController.eventStore = eventStore;
addController.event=event;

// present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
[parent presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

addController.editViewDelegate = self;
[addController release];
```