# Is it possible to add attendees in EKEvent (in iPhone Native calendar app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, icalendar

Does any one know how to add contact( attendees and organizer property) name in EKEvent(native calendar application).
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913061/initialize-event-in-ekeventeditviewcontroller it may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for giving link but problem with attendees and organizer property of EKEvent is that ,these are readonly property. But native ical is handling these two property when we sync it with google.If there is any contact name associated with event in the google calendar then that event with the contact comes there in the native ical.So programmatically How can I add contact to the event.